# can't open zap.sh

Tags: command-line

I extract `zap.tar`, and it has `zap.sh`. But when I type `sh zap.sh` in terminal, it shows cannot open zap.sh. So what can I do with it? I need it to complete my homework.

Comment: in terminal, run: `chmod +x zap.sh`. That makes it executable. Also, just read the content with an editor, to see what it does. After that, you can just typ in: `./zap.sh`.

Comment: What the exact error message? What are the current permissions on the file? Shown by running `ls -l zip.sh`

Comment: Also if you're not in the directory that contains `zap.sh` you'll need to provide the path to the file.

Answer (score 5):

As I have mentioned in my comment:

- First, open up your terminal(<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), then extract the tar file, in your current directory:

  ```
  tar -xvf zap.tar
  ```

  This assumes that you're in your home folder(`~`, which is `/home/YourUsername/`). If not, `cd` to where your script is in, like so: `cd ~/Downloads/script/`
- Then make it executable, by running:

  ```
  chmod +x zap.sh
  ```
- Finally, the file can be executed from the terminal with:

  ```
  ./zap.sh
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Move to the directory containing the script:

```
cd ~/path/to/script
```

Make it executable:

```
chmod +x zap.sh
```

Run it:

```
./zap.sh
```

Comment: You should add that your commands assume that `zap.sh` is located in the current working directory.

Answer (score -1):

`zap.sh: 98: zap.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected`

Error installing all the java things, so Pls  go to the relevant folder, cd ZaPsomething

```
chmod +x zap.sh
./zap.sh
```

Comment: Please edit to fix grammar and formatting :)

Comment: Keeps giving and error:./zap.sh
Found Java version 1.8.0_131
Available memory: 32063 MB
Setting jvm heap size: -Xmx8015m
173 [main] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.GuiBootstrap  - OWASP ZAP 2.6.0 started 15/05/17 09:41:43
264 [main] ERROR org.zaproxy.zap.ZAP$UncaughtExceptionLogger  - Exception in thread "main"
java.awt.AWTError: Assistive Technology not found: org.GNOME.Accessibility.AtkWrapper